# Angular amplify-authenticator shows wrong state when navigating to another page

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

I am using `amplify-authenticator` with different `initialState` to show the amplify form with different states depending on the needs. So on the login page I use the detault initialState (which is 'signIn'):

```
<amplify-authenticator
    [services]="amplifyServices"
    [loginMechanisms]="['email']"
    [hideSignUp]="true">
</amplify-authenticator>
```

Below this form i have a button to go to the 'Forgot password' page, where I show another amplify form with the initialState of 'resetPassword':

```
<amplify-authenticator [services]="services" initialState="resetPassword">
    <ng-template 
        amplifySlot="authenticated"
        let-user="user"
        let-signOut="signOut"
    ></ng-template>
</amplify-authenticator>
```

The problem is this: when I first enter the login page, everything looks fine, but when I click on 'Forgot password' and I navigate to that page, the initialState of resetPassword is ignored and I see the 'signIn' state. If I refresh the page, the correct form is displayed. The same problem appears when I refresh the page on the forgot password page and I navigate to the login page - there I see the resetPassword form instead on the signIn one. After refresh, everything looks fine again.

Maybe amplify is not configured properly, because this problem appeared after an upgrade I made to the application.
I moved to Angular 16 and

```
"@aws-amplify/ui-angular": "^2.1.3" => "@aws-amplify/ui-angular": "4.0.3"
"aws-amplify": "^4.3.14" => "aws-amplify": "5.3.5"
```

I checked the documentation from Amplify, but I couldn't find where the problem is, or what changed at their end. Please advise! Thanks!

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you find any solution yet